# How can I know if a client is using prepared statements?

Tags: mysql

When I use client libraries like `MySQLdb` or `oursql`, how can I know if it's using prepared statements or not?

Is there anyway I can tell the difference on the server side? Maybe by looking into some kind of logs?

**EDIT**: I'm using MySQL5.1

Comment: It'll be obvious: first, you'll pass the parameters separately from the query. Second, reading the API documentation should make it abundantly clear.

Comment: Or put another way, client libraries use prepared statements *or not*, depending on what you tell them to do.

Comment: @MattBall Some libraries like `MySQLdb` present an interface that makes you think it's using prepared statement, but it's just an emulated one.

Comment: @zerkms Please read my question, I'm asking how to tell the difference on the server side.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic: my fault, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the client *has* permission to use stored procs, you must use logging of some form.

If you have control of the client, you can have the client log all requests and examine that log.

If you don't have control of the client, you can turn on detailed logging at the db server and examine the SQL statements vs client id.

If you don't have that kind of control over the database, you can "log" from within the stored proc(s) by modifying them to also insert into a log table the user making the request and the timestamp etc.

These options are presented roughly in the order of preference.

---

Read [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html) for what's involved in turning on General Query Logging. A précis from that link:

> The general query log is a general record of what mysqld is doing. The server writes information to this log when clients connect or disconnect, and **it logs each SQL statement received from clients**.

As of MySQL5.1, you can enable `general_log` at runtime: `SET GLOBAL general_log = 1`

And use `SELECT @@general_log_file` to locate the log file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Would you please explain more on what kind of log should be enabled to see queries?

Comment: You would have to consult the mysql doc for start up settings regarding logging. Also, see edits.

Comment: @Bohemian: I'm also curious - how would you tell if the query is a plain-text one or prepared using logs?

Comment: @zerkms since the preparation of the statement is itself a statement, that should be logged. If the plain query isn't logged when subsequently executed, I imagine you would probably find some kind of statement id in the log, and that same id logged when the prepared statement was executed. Such logging is designed to be useful after all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the MySQL general_log table/feature. You would see PREPARE statements in there from clients that are using it.